# Generate regular connected gridlines using expand.grid R

Tags: r, grid

I would like to generate a regular grid in R. 
This is what I get using the following code and data:

[image]

How can one possibly generate connected lines and not pluses?I will be overlaying this grid on a map of my study area.
Thanks for your suggestions.

```
library(sp)
sample_test <- sample  # 
sample_test$x <- sample_test$x  # define x & y as longitude and latitude
sample_test$y <- sample_test$y
coordinates(sample_test) = ~x + y
plot(sample_test)
x.range <- as.numeric(c(-128.00138, -87.99081))  
y.range <- as.numeric(c(44.44628,62))  
grd1 <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], 
                            by = 1.5), y = seq(from = y.range[1], 
                                               to = y.range[2], by = 1.5))  # expand points to grid
coordinates(grd1) <- ~x + y
gridded(grd1) <- TRUE
plot(grd1, cex = 1.5, col = "black",lwd=3,lty=1)


structure(list(x = c(-96.76999664, -97.23000336, -97.08000183, 
    -97.02999878, -95.69999695, -97.01999664, -99.27999878, -96, 
    -95.19999695, -96.06999969, -100.0500031, -101.2300034, -98.80000305, 
    -99.56999969, -101.8799973, -101.0999985, -94.06999969, -94.72000122, 
    -101.0800018, -97.84999847, -97.87000275, -112.8700027, -111.1999969, 
    -113.75, -114.0999985, -111.3499985, -114.0199966, -113.7300034, 
    -113.3799973, -113.0500031, -112.8000031, -110.7200012, -113.6299973, 
    -113.9800034, -112.1299973, -110.4700012, -115.5500031, -114.1800003, 
    -114.4800034, -114.3700027, -118.0299988, -113.2799988, -117.5299988, 
    -114.6800003, -116.4499969, -116.3000031, -111.2200012, -114.7799988, 
    -115.7799988, -119.4000015, -118.5299988, -111.1200027, -116.0299988, 
    -118.8799973, -117.6200027, -117.4499969, -113.8300018, -110.2799988, 
    -102.2799988, -104.6500015, -101.7799988, -105.9800034, -102.9700012, 
    -103.6500015, -103.75, -102.0999985, -105.5500031, -101.6699982, 
    -103.9199982, -104.6699982, -104.1800003, -102.2300034, -107.3000031, 
    -109.5, -106.6500015, -107.9300003, -108.9199982, -107.7300034, 
    -107.8499985, -106.3799973, -109.1800003, -108.25, -108.8300018, 
    -109.4000015, -104.5999985, -107.0500031, -105.1500015, -105.6699982, 
    -106.7200012, -108.4300003, -108.4800034, -103.6999969, -107.1299973, 
    -102.3499985, -105.6200027, -105.2699966, -109.0999985, -106.0699997, 
    -103.1500015, -104, -102.5800018, -101.8700027, -101.0500031, 
    -99.94999695, -99.08000183, -101.2699966, -98.26999664, -97.23000336, 
    -99.65000153, -98.08000183, -95.59999847, -113.8499985, -112.8199997, 
    -111.4499969, -113.5800018, -111.0699997, -111.7300034, -114.9199982, 
    -114.1200027, -112.7200012), y = c(49.52999878, 49.91999817, 
    50.93000031, 52.34999847, 51.02999878, 50.63000107, 53.15000153, 
    50.47000122, 49.61999893, 50.18000031, 51.09999847, 52.11999893, 
    50.41999817, 50.15000153, 54.77000046, 53.97000122, 58.72999954, 
    56.34999847, 56.86999893, 53.97000122, 55.79999924, 51.47000122, 
    50.72000122, 52.45000076, 51.77999878, 51.58000183, 51.11999893, 
    49.93000031, 49, 50.88000107, 49.63000107, 50.02000046, 49.13000107, 
    49.52000046, 50.04999924, 49.11999893, 51.20000076, 49.47000122, 
    49.63000107, 50.54999924, 52.93000031, 54.72000122, 53.40000153, 
    54.13000107, 53.58000183, 55.41999817, 56.65000153, 55.27999878, 
    54.15000153, 55.20000076, 56.08000183, 58.77000046, 58.38000107, 
    55.18000031, 57.75, 56.22999954, 55.97000122, 54.41999817, 50.90000153, 
    49.38000107, 51.52000046, 51.27000046, 49.22000122, 50.54999924, 
    51.25, 49.61999893, 50.33000183, 50.13000107, 51.97999954, 50.43000031, 
    49.81999969, 51.20000076, 49.72000122, 50.90000153, 50.47000122, 
    50.97999954, 49.68000031, 50.27000046, 49.36999893, 49, 51.52000046, 
    52.77000046, 52.36999893, 53.13000107, 52.81999969, 51.47999954, 
    52.41999817, 53.22000122, 52.16999817, 55.83000183, 59.56999969, 
    58.18000031, 57.34999847, 55.52999878, 57.25, 55.15000153, 54.04999924, 
    53.91999817, 56.22999954, 53.33000183, 52.88000107, 52.08000183, 
    50.43000031, 49.91999817, 49.54999924, 49.18000031, 49.95000076, 
    49, 49.41999817, 49.18000031, 49.02000046, 53.27999878, 53.02999878, 
    52.06999969, 53.31999969, 53.88000107, 53.41999817, 52.41999817, 
    53.88000107, 52.33000183), z = c(2.828473713, 2.816217406, 2.509009307, 
    2.259404198, 2.764477168, 2.656714485, 2.421834218, 2.501955178, 
    3.145913327, 2.807657891, 2.513891257, 2.528999208, 2.46200098, 
    2.583228119, 2.382176416, 2.35432104, 1.918549307, 2.402386475, 
    2.558620396, 2.538944238, 2.610964693, 1.99243196, 1.756681188, 
    2.642281465, 2.740559327, 2.009994257, 2.399834089, 2.130669465, 
    1.967594663, 1.840109851, 1.899634574, 1.635899663, 2.465839614, 
    2.255109149, 1.553891307, 1.439496277, 1.943356941, 2.304925663, 
    1.929266119, 2.473220545, 1.921665861, 2.725758554, 2.729624139, 
    2.770081604, 3.132900594, 2.495621386, 2.539078287, 2.728228119, 
    3.263039347, 2.297555188, 2.259231564, 1.894044158, 1.86533596, 
    2.338287465, 2.382499703, 2.050684376, 2.569541733, 2.531321297, 
    2.298776594, 2.023563158, 2.387554812, 1.980406733, 2.262704901, 
    2.202542802, 2.416568891, 2.33382904, 2.178382218, 2.593413267, 
    2.333317396, 2.113645515, 2.159429485, 2.426607842, 1.757212871, 
    1.847136218, 1.958802277, 1.737457198, 1.890041109, 1.884000723, 
    1.723499208, 1.926405396, 1.857674376, 2.191072337, 2.028084614, 
    2.453978119, 2.210926238, 1.827849069, 2.317268535, 2.378235535, 
    1.933085317, 2.433379762, 1.70934901, 2.516750812, 2.523765, 
    2.546187614, 2.533181069, 2.554832931, 2.38163505, 2.391062772, 
    2.557342376, 2.328782931, 2.514206228, 2.791659851, 2.590188366, 
    2.533634772, 2.74040205, 2.284591594, 2.657379485, 2.864480218, 
    2.592742228, 2.671169307, 3.239024257, 2.858997861, 2.542652109, 
    2.129844188, 2.799368109, 2.434033772, 2.644536168, 3.169544238, 
    2.848915911, 2.719405624)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -120L))
```

Comment: try using `abline(h=seq(...))` amd `abline(v=seq(...))` to add horizintal and vertucal lines respectively

Comment: @user20650 please show me how to add these lines using my data. I could not figure it out after many trials. Thanks.

Comment: `with(grd1, plot(x,y)) ; abline(h=seq(min(grd1$y),max(grd1$y), 1)) ; abline(v=seq(min(grd1$x),max(grd1$x), 1)) ` . There is also the `grid()` function if you dont need as much control over the spacing